# Is it possible (and safe) to make an accepting socket non-blocking?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, fcntl

I'm looking for a way to interrupt an [`accept()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/accept.html) call on a blocking socket. Using signals is not an option, as this is meant to be in a library and I don't want to clutter the user signals. Using `select()` is another option, buf for various reason it's not very appealing in my case.

What would work well, if possible, is to set the socket to non-blocking mode (using [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) and `O_NONBLOCK`) from another thread, while the socket is blocked on an `accept()` call. The expected behaviour is that the `accept()` call will return with `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` in `errno`.

Would it indeed work like that? Is it safe? Portable?

If you know about the applicability of this method to Windows (where you need to use [`WSAIoctl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FONBIO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), I'm also interested.

Comment: `fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);` did the trick for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No idea about Windows, but the behavior you want is guaranteed by POSIX:

> If the listen queue is empty of connection requests and O_NONBLOCK is not set on the file descriptor for the socket, accept() shall block until a connection is present. If the listen() queue is empty of connection requests and O_NONBLOCK is set on the file descriptor for the socket, accept() shall fail and set errno to [EAGAIN] or [EWOULDBLOCK].

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html

Also, `select` or `poll` can be used to check for incoming connections by polling for the listening socket in the reading set.

Comment: Are you sure an already blocking `accept()` would return as specified, if the file descriptor having been passed gets `O_NONBLOCK` set asynchronously? Your quote seems ambiguous to me for this case.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. No, I don't think changing the mode to non-blocking while it's already blocked is portable. Why don't you just make it nonblocking to begin with, and use `poll` or `select` prior to the `accept` call, and only call `accept` if a connection is available? There are plenty of clean ways to make `select` or `poll` return early, like the self-pipe trick.

Comment: Okay, so the definite answer is that it's not up possible. Both in theory and practice (I ended up trying it out, both on Linux and Windows).

Comment: On windows you should use OVERLAPPED io. For portability I would suggest using Boost Asio.

Comment: On Windows (WinSock) you can actually just close the socket from another thread. This will unblock any threads blocking on that socket.

Comment: @JamieB: That is not a safe operation ever, and carries with it the possibility of something else being opened on the same fd number, which the accept could continue on after interruption by a signal.

Answer (score 1):

In the question, You are saying that you do not want to use select (or poll or epoll) which are the best ways for IO multiplexing. I would recommend you using one another thread just for listening sockets while this is a bad idea!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question was asked 8 years ago. In truth, I do not even remember what I was trying to achieve back then!