# Stop accepting new connections

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking

I want to stop accepting connection from the main thread .. I have copied the original code here. in this server. it spawn a new thread per each connection. there is a seperate thread to clean the connection pool and another thread for user command processing all works perfectly.  i just want to stop accepting new connection based on user commands. the accept method exists within the main thread i used the following logic to stop accepting

```
while (bListening && (sctCommSocket = accept(sctBaseSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&addrClient,&c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
```

but after setting bListening to true.. the loop still accept 1 connection.. but this was not expected. please explain

Comment: It might be easier to not fix this, but simply disconnect the unwanted connection.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the flag the loop was already blocked in `accept()`, so it accepted the next connection.

Comment: I undersand the logical trap.. can you suggest a solution.. is there any pausing mechanism rather trying this way

Comment: If you want to stop accepting, close the listening socket. Nothing else will do because of the listen backlog queue.

Answer (score -1):

This is very similar to the question asked here: [Is it possible (and safe) to make an accepting socket non-blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861956/is-it-possible-and-safe-to-make-an-accepting-socket-non-blocking)

I think that will solve your problem too although it's not clear from the code snippet what operating system and multithreading library you are using.

Edit:

Here's a good guide on network programming: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

A section that addresses the blocking problem specifically is http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#Blocking

There are multiple ways to address this issue and which is the "best" will depend on your specific case. As a commenter suggested, you will have to setup the socket to be non-blocking before you call accept the first time.

Comment: The comments in your link clearly state that changing the blocking mode won't affect an `accept()` that is already in progress.

Comment: @EJP Right; you have to set it up to be non-blocking before calling it. Then you have to write extra code around it to stop calling it once bListening is false. The link explains how to make accept() non-blocking so then the calling code can be modified to do what the asker wants.