# Breaking a WHILE Loop with a Function (+ a blocking Function)

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am working on a program using threads to treat demands of remote clients in C++. The server will **wait for clients** to connect, and launch a thread doing some things.
For the server to shut down, the user must do an external interrupt <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and the code will handle the signal (using [<csignal>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/csignal)) in order to shut everything properly.

The waiting itself is made with a `while` loop, the server waits for a connection, and launches the thread. It's during this loop that I want to handle the signal. Here it is:

```
std::signal(SIGINT, interruptHandler);
while(intStatus != 2){
        ClientSocket client;
        client.csock = accept(sock,reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&(client.csin)),&(client.crecsize));

        tArray.push_back(new pthread_t);
        pthread_create(tArray.back(), NULL, session, &client);
}
std::cout<<"Waiting for Clients to exit..."<<std::endl;
for(pthread_t* thread : tArray)
        pthread_join(*thread,NULL);
```

- `std::sig_atomic_t intStatus` is a global variable edited by `interruptHandler` when it's called.
- `ClientSocket` is a `struct` containing informations about the client:

  - `csoc` the socket of the client
  - `csin` the adress of the socket
  - `crecsize` gives the size of the data to send (I think)
- I am using [<winsock2.h>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/) to connect between server and clients. `sock` is the socket of the server.
- I am using [<pthread.h>](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html) to manage threads. They are stored in `std::list<pthread_t*> tArray`.

The problem is : because `accept()` pauses the process, and of course the loop must end to see if  <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> has been sent, the server can only shut down when an additional client connects.

Is there a way for `interruptHandler()` to break the `while` and let the program go ahead with the `for` loop and next? Should I change the algorithm? On a last resort I know we can set up tags in Assembly for the program to jump to. Is there a way to do this in C++ too?

By the way, I am using <pthread.h> and <winsock2.h> because I have too (it's a student project). Thanks for helping.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861956/is-it-possible-and-safe-to-make-an-accepting-socket-non-blocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Blindy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108796/blindy), I digged up about [select(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) and came up with something. I will try to explain it here instead of marking [@Blindy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108796/blindy)'s answer as solution, since it took me some time to make it work and I want to save people from the headaches I had.

Here is the new `while` loop, using `select()` :

```
#include <csignal>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>  
#include <sys/ioctl.h>   //On Unix (with some other includes)

...

    //The Server will only shut down if CRTL+C is sent
    std::signal(SIGINT, interruptHandler);

    //Make the socket non-blocking
    int success = 1;
    int nonBlocking = 1;
    //If success = -1 : Error in ioctlsocket(), if success = 1 : ioctlsocket() wasn't called
    //Optional condition, for portability sake.
    #if defined (WIN32)
        //if on Windows
        success = ioctlsocket(sock,FIONBIO,&nonBlocking);
    #else
        //if on Unix (or else)
        success = ioctl(sock,FIONBIO,&nonBlocking);
    #endif
    if(success != 0) throw std::runtime_error("ioctlsocket() failed, code : "+std::to_string(success));                    

    //Declaration of variables needed for select() :
    fd_set readSet;   //A set of Sockets used to call listen() - here there is only one
    timeval inter;    //The time interval during select() is waiting for a pending connection

    int res;          //Declaration of the variable storing select()'s return
    while(intStatus != 2){       
        //Reseting readSet
        FD_ZERO(&readSet);
        FD_SET(sock, &readSet);
        //Reseting inter, select() modifying it on Unix
        inter = {0,50};         //The select() will wait 50ms before retrying

        res = select(4097,&readSet,NULL,NULL,&inter);
        if(res == -1){                       //If select() did not finish
            if(errno == EINTR)  continue;    //If it was because of CRTL+C
            else                throw std::runtime_error("Select() failed.");
        } 
        if(res == 0)            continue;    //If no connections are pending

        //If the new readSet modified by select() still has the socket in it
        if(!FD_ISSET(sock,&readSet))    throw std::runtime_error("The socket is no longer in readfds");

        ClientSocket client;
        client.sock = accept(sock,reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&(client.sin)),&(client.recsize));

        tArray.push_back(new pthread_t);
        pthread_create(tArray.back(), NULL, session, &client);

    }
```

I hope it's somewhat clear and I didn't do mistakes. Tell me if something is wrong, I will edit it. Thanks again, Blindy !

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is : because accept() pauses the process, and of course the loop must end to see if Crtl+C has been sent, the server can only shut down when an additional client connects.

[`accept`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) blocks, that is true, but you can use [`select`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to check if you have incoming connections, guaranteeing that if you call `accept` at that point you won't block.